# Using angularjs without boostrap as "front-end ui framework"

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I've fallen in love with angularjs, though it's a new concept to me coming from a java backend background. The question is, is it possible to use another "front-end" UI framework besides twitter bootstrap, like Metro-UI-CSS, Gumby, TopCoat etc? Not that I'm 100% on this but, it seems to me that most of these "front-end" UI frameworks use jquery/javascript to enhance the behavior of ui elements and such, so would it be still possible to use these frameworks with angularjs? Can you please provide a link of an example of this.

Thanks

Comment: Yes it is possible, but I think your question is too general.  Angular doesn't care about what front end framework you use, however you as the developer may need to write some directives to make it all work together.

Comment: @lucuma Thanks for your quick reply, I know it's quite a general question especially with no code attempt from my side but as I'm a noob I just wanted an overview cos all examples I've come across use bootstrap. FYI, I've just ran into this article: [link] https://github.com/caitp/angular-semantic [link], seconding your view on the use of directives to make things work together. Thanks again

Comment: Directives are the general glue for making other frameworks play nice with Angular.  They aren't always required and you can sometimes get away with the jquery passthrough (http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/#/jq).  It all just depends however you're asking us to write an example for you when you should try first and then ask a question about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the official Angular UI , which is the port of Boostrap to Angular Directives , have a look here http://angular-ui.github.io/

Comment: Thanks Radix, will most definitely look into this. Please see the link in the comment above, should you be also interested